# who to find dynamic class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

we are trying to find the class name dynamic but we only find the first div name when we click on other link too.

js code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#foot-map .maplink a').on('click', function(){
    var mapFlag = $(this).closest('#foot-map').find('.map-area div').attr('class');

    alert(mapFlag);

});

});
```

please find the full code on this link:- [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/Lsn6wdvo/)

Comment: what is the requirement?

Comment: *"please find the full code on this link"* No. Instead, put all the necessary information **in** your question, not just linked. See: [mcve] See also: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What is the code meant to do?

Comment: you can use this button `<>` to add a demo

Comment: because your code $(this).closest('#foot-map').find('.map-area div').attr('class') will always  return the same element

Comment: because the closest `div` having `map-area` class to list elements, is the first one -))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you only see the value from the first div is because there are multiple elements in the jQuery collection, and calling `attr()` on that collection will only return the first one.

To achieve what you required you could place an additional `data` attribute on the `<a>` elements which can be used to target the specific `.map-area` div related to the `a`, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foot-map .maplink a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var mapFlag = $(this).closest('#foot-map').find('.map-area .' + target).attr('class');
    alert(mapFlag);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foot-map">
  <ul class="maplink">
    <li><a id="uktabfoot" data-target="uk" class="active" href="#">UK</a></li>
    <li><a id="maltatabfoot" data-target="malta" href="#">MALTA</a></li>
    <li><a id="indiatabfoot" data-target="india" href="#">INDIA</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="map-area">
    <div class="uk map-hover">
      <a href="#"><b></b></a>
      <span class="flag">United Kingdom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="malta">
      <a href="¢"><b></b></a>
      <span class="flag">Malta</span>
    </div>
    <div class="india">
      <a href="#"><b></b></a>
      <span class="flag">India</span>
    </div>
    <div class="china">
      <a href="#"><b></b></a>
      <span class="flag">China</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that placing `javascript:` in a `href` attribute is not ideal. If you don't want the URL to be affected by clicking the element, make the `href` a `#` and prevent the event by using `return false`, or preferably by calling `preventDefault()` on the raised event.